# PHP Array values from file_get_contents

Tags: php, arrays

I declared one variables like this

```
echo $OPTIONS="500=>250.00, 1000=>500.00,2500=>1100.00,5000=>2250.00";
```

and

I got this variables through `file_get_contents()` functions.

```
$contents = file_get_contents(SERVICE_URL."options_config.php?options=".$OPTIONS);
$package=array($contents)
foreach($package as $pack=>$price)
{
echo $pack;
}
```

But I got 0 values. What is the problem?

```
print_r($package);
```

The result is :

```
Array ( [0] => 500=>250.00, 1000=>500.00,2500=>1100.00,5000=>2250.00 )
```

I want the result like this

```
500 as 250.00
1000 as 500.00
```

Comment: just `print_r($package[0])` you will have the way you want.

Comment: plus, the codes listed has syntax error on line 2, missing a semi-colon

Comment: `$package=array($contents)` — You can't dynamically initialize an array like that. You'll have to do some string manipulation (using string functions, regex etc.) to create the array first. Only then will you be able to loop through it. (Use `var_dump()` to inspect what a particular variable contains.)

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty: That'd be useless since `$package` will always contain a single entry. It'd be the same as doing `echo array('foo')[0];` (which will always print `foo`).

Comment: yeah thats correct @AmalMurali if not single entry then it needs to be looped.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty: `file_get_contents` will return a string. `$package` will be an array containing just a single entry (the string from `f_g_c()`). The OP needs to print the values inside the string. It isn't possible without some string manipulation (unless you use `eval()`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is [serialize](http://php.net/serialize) and [unserialize](http://php.net/unserialize)

Example: **test.php**

```
<?php

// Handle Get Request
// This portion of your code can be on another file
//
if (isset($_GET['getOptions']))
{
    $myOptions = array(
        500  => 250.00,
        1000 => 500.00,
        2500 => 1100.00,
        5000 => 2250.00
    );
    exit(serialize($myOptions));
}

// Sample Usage
$options = file_get_contents('http://localhost/test.php?getOptions');
$options = unserialize($options);

// Debug
var_dump($options);

?>
```

Outputs:

[image]